# How can I change the location of my 'Documents' folder in Fedora 16?

Tags: fedora

I have dual boot Fedora 16 and Windows 7 on my computer, with a third partition holding my documents, music, videos, and pictures. I've made it so Windows points to that partition for those folders, but I can't get Fedora to. I swear I saw a window at one point that let me change the location for them, but I can't for the life of me find it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, add (or replace) the following lines:

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Put your desired path between quotation marks. (Paths in this file must start with either `/` or `$HOME/`.)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I still wish I could find that window, though. It's possible that was in Windows.